# Binding to DependencyProperty TextBox vs. TextBlock

Tags: c#, wpf, dependency-properties

I encountered a problem, which must be so simple and obvious, but I cannot figure out what I’m doing wrong. It is almost embarrassing.

The objective is simple. I want to use dependency-properties in a custom user-control to bind to.

The Control AssetSelctorControl.xaml:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Ey.Ventuz.SessionManager.Ui.AssetSelctorControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ey.Ventuz.SessionManager.Ui"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="80" d:DesignWidth="400" Height="Auto" >
<Grid d:DataContext="{x:Static local:AssetSelectorDesignViewModel.Instance}"
      ShowGridLines="False"
      Background="{StaticResource DefaultDarkGrayBrush}"
      Margin="4">
    <StackPanel>
    <TextBox Grid.Column="0"
               TextWrapping="Wrap"
               
               Text="{Binding AssetAddress}"
               x:Name="assetAddressTextBox"
               Margin="4 0"/>
    <Button Content="Browse" Style="{StaticResource BaseButton}" Margin="6"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

Code behind AssetSelctorControl.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace Ey.Ventuz.SessionManager.Ui
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaktionslogik für AssetSelctorControl.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class AssetSelctorControl : UserControl
    {
        public AssetSelctorControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string AssetAddress
        {
            get { return (string)GetValue(AssetAddressProperty); }
            set 
            { 
                SetValue(AssetAddressProperty, value); 
            }
        }


        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Caption.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty AssetAddressProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("AssetAddress", typeof(string), typeof(AssetSelctorControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, PropertyChangedCallback));

        private static void PropertyChangedCallback(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
        {
            AssetSelctorControl userControl = ((AssetSelctorControl)dependencyObject);
            userControl.assetAddressTextBox.Text = (string)args.NewValue;
        }
    }
}
```

Where it is used:

```
UserControl x:Class="Ey.Ventuz.SessionManager.Ui.WidgetModuleTeamGalleryControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Ey.Ventuz.SessionManager.Ui"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         x:Name="myAsset"
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid Background="{StaticResource DefaultDarkGrayBrush}" 
      VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="40" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <StackPanel Grid.Row="0" 
                Orientation="Horizontal" 
                VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <TextBlock Text="Headline:"
                   Style="{StaticResource ModuleCaption}" />
        <TextBox x:Name="test" 
                 Style="{StaticResource TextBox}" 
                 Text="{Binding Headline, Mode=TwoWay}" Margin="5"/>
    </StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" 
               Text="Team:" 
               Style="{StaticResource ModuleCaption}" />
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="2" 
                  VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
        <ItemsControl Margin="5"
                      ItemsSource="{Binding Gallery, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                      x:Name="pplList">
            <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Border BorderBrush="{StaticResource DefaultGrayBrush}" Height="Auto" BorderThickness="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5">
                        <StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5 0">
                                <TextBlock Text="Name:" Style="{StaticResource ModuleCaption}" />
                                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBox}" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="5"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5 0">
                                <TextBlock Text="Description:" Style="{StaticResource ModuleCaption}" />
                                <TextBox Style="{StaticResource TextBox}" Text="{Binding Description}" Margin="5"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="5 0">
                                <local:AssetSelctorControl AssetAddress="{Binding Picture}" Width="250"/>
                            </StackPanel>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </Border>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        </ItemsControl>
    </ScrollViewer>
</Grid>
```

So basically just this:

```
<local:AssetSelctorControl AssetAddress="{Binding Picture}" Width="250"/>
```

Now, when I change the textbox-control in the custom user control to a textblock-control, everything works great and the value appears. The textbox however won’t display the value.
Please help. Going bananas here.
Thanks.

Comment: Since you bind the value in your user control, your user control also should implement `INotifyPropertyChange` interface in order to reflect the changes.

Comment: `Text="{Binding AssetAddress, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"`

Comment: @Clemens Thank you. I'm still confused why it would still work in a textblock without referring to the relativer source. But thanks. it did the Trick.

Comment: You should also remove the PropertyChangedCallback for AssetAddress.

Comment: @Clemens did that. Thank you so much. It works. Can you point me to I source where I can learn more about the reasoning behind all this?

Comment: MS online documentation is pretty good IMO. For a book, I can recommend "WPF Unleashed* by Adam Nathan.

Comment: @Eldar That's not true. Dependency properties provide their own change notifications.